# postsharp aspects result in exception being thrown at "end" of method

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I am using PostSharp in C#, for using AOP in my codebase.  Recently i've noticed that errors are not being thrown where they are actually thrown, but at the end of the method which was weaved with any aspect.  For example, take the sample code below:

```
    public void methodUsingAspects()
    {
        doSomething1();
        doSomethingWhichThrowsError(); //an error is thrown in this method
        doSomething2();
    } //in visual studio, while debugging, the debugger stops at this line (end of method), not at the actual line the error got thrown.
```

The error gets shown as if thrown where there is the last curly bracket `}`.  This is quite frustrating especially when the error is thrown quite deep inside the calls the method does.

I can assume why this is done, since the code is changed - but is it possible to somehow leave it work as it was before?